# Tomcat: Load Classes Copied into WEB-INF/lib at Web App Startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, tomcat8

My organization is creating a "base" Java web app that is meant to be customized by adding jar files (with customized classes) by adding the jar files to the web app's `WEB-INF/lib` directory.  The goal is that our developers can simply create custom code, packaged as a simple jar file, which can be loaded into this "base" web app, so the developer doesn't have to worry about all the web app plumbing, just the actual custom code.

We're investigating a few different deployment models, but one idea was to put these jar files somewhere on a network directory.  When the Java web app starts up, a `ServletContextListener` copies these jar files into the web app's `WEB-INF/lib` directory (the web app is originally deployed as a `war` file).

Then, another `ServletContextListener` uses Stripes' `ResolverUtil` class ([JavaDoc here](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/index.html?overview-summary.html)) to load all of the classes of a particular type (in this case, that implement a particular interface) that are located in the jar files that were copied into `WEB-INF/lib`.

Unfortunately, `ResolverUtil` fails to find those classes, even though they are in those copied jars.  If I restart Tomcat (with those jar files still in `WEB-INF/lib`) they are found, as expected.

The jar files need to be in `WEB-INF/lib` because we want to use the Servlet 3.0 feature in which JSPs can be served from jar files, and for that to work, apparently those jar files need to be in `WEB-INF/lib`.  If that weren't the case we would just add those jar files in the `shared.loader` property in `catalina.properties`.

So, it appears that Tomcat has already scanned the classpath for all class definitions by the time a web app is started, and since those jar files weren't in `WEB-INF/lib` when the web app started up, the classes will not be found.

Is there a way for those classes to be found?  I don't need Tomcat to completely reload itself; I just need those new jar files and the class files they contain to be visible to the class loader.  Is there a way to tell the classloader, "Hey, check the classpath again for new jars!" as I would only need to do it once, when the web app starts up?

Any other ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: This would be possible, but in my opinion very complicated. You would have to get the ClassLoader of the WebApp, use a URLClassLoader with the webapp ClassLoader as parent. Or in other words: You need to implement your own deployment mechanism.

Comment: To get a rough idea how classloading in tomcat is working I would suggest debugging through the tomcat sourcecode step by step. This may take some time (several hours or days) but afterwards some of the "magic" is demystified and one knows where to look for if msyterious errors occur. I did this by myself for learning about WebSocket handling in the latest tomcat 7 releases.